# Getting a syntax error while executing SQLite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am attempting to use a SQLite database to store emails locally in android. When I first call `context.getWritableDatabase()`, the database does not yet exist and is created.  I am getting a syntax error on the create statement... My code looks like this...

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "views.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_VIEWS = "views";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";
    private static final String KEY_FROM = "from";
    private static final String KEY_UNREAD = "unread";
    private static final String KEY_SUBJECT = "subject";
    private static final String KEY_BODY = "body";


    // Database creation sql statement
    private static final String CREATE_VIEWS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_VIEWS + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
            + KEY_INDEX + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_UNREAD + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
            + KEY_SUBJECT + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_FROM + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
            + KEY_BODY + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

I am new to SQLite syntax and I have been searching for what could cause this with no avail.  Any idea whats causing this? A database is really the best way to store such data locally.

The exact error reads as follows..

```
07-01 17:54:42.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3036): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "index": syntax error: CREATE TABLE views (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,index INTEGER NOT NULL,unread TEXT NOT NULL,subject TEXT NOT NULL,from TEXT NOT NULL,body TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use the keyword 'index' as your table column name, change it to something else like tbl_index instead.

Comment: Might have a problem with `KEY_FROM = "from"` too. Double quoting the offending names (everywhere!) is an option as well, not a very pleasant option but an option nonetheless.